# Странное изменение результата запроса в Oracle 11

Tags: sql, oracle

1) Запрос возвращает 100 записей с нумерацией:

```
select rownum as rrr, 
t.* 
from (
select a.id
from acts a
where a.id=a.parent_act_id
and a.status_id=0
and rownum<=100
order by 1
) t
```

2) Есть функция возвращающая константу (return number deterministic)
get_const('project') - возвращает всегда 0 
Можно получить те же 100 записей, но без нумерации

```
select --rownum as rrr, 
t.* 
from (
select a.id
from acts a
where a.id=a.parent_act_id
and a.status_id=get_const('project')
and rownum<=100
order by 1
) t
```

3) А вот это непонятно: запрос не возвращает ничего хотя просто раскомментировали нумерацию

```
select rownum as rrr, 
t.* 
from (
select a.id
from acts a
where a.id=a.parent_act_id
and a.status_id=get_const('project')
and rownum<=100
order by 1
) t
```

В чем может быть причина?

Уточнение:

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MYCONSTANTS as   
           project const number(1) := 0;
        end MYCONSTANTS;
        /

        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_const 
     (
      p_const_name   in varchar2
     ,p_package_name in varchar2 default 'MYCONSTANTS'
     ) return number deterministic
    is
      l_result number;
    begin
execute immediate 'begin :l_result := "'||upper(p_package_name)||'"."'||upper(p_const_name)||'"; end;' using out l_result;
      return l_result;
    end get_const;
    /
```

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.4.0  Production"

Comment: На первое место надо вынести  выборку  `t.*` а потом уже нумерацию.. `select t.*, rownum as rrr ...`. А откуда вообще нумерация берётся `rownum`?

Comment: Не могу [воспроизвести](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3da3a7/1). Поправте тестовые данные, если считаете, что в этом дело.

Comment: добавил уточнение

Comment: В чём заключается уточнение? Как понял, вы добавили пакет, который нигде не используется. Измените данные или объекты схемы по ссылке в моём комментарии выше и опубликуйте новую ссылку.

Comment: пакет используется для получения константы. На самом деле в пакете куча констант. По ссылке добавить не могу - что-то не хочет понимать execute immediate в коде

Comment: 1) "пакет используется" - а где исползуется? В запросе вы используете отдельную фунцию  2) Вы писали - "функция возвращающая константу (return number deterministic) get_const('project') - возвращает всегда 0" - а зачем нужно  `execute immediate`? А если просто всегда возвращать 0, т.е.     `return 0`, то ошибка не воспроизводится?

Comment: 1) пакет используется в самой функции 2) Вы правы - на БД воспроизвелось и просто при return 0 -  а на sqlfiddle не могу повторить